# Parsing when a literal is inside of a string

Tags: parsing, antlr4, grammar

When trying to parse the following:

`openapi is not valid`

`spec is not 1234abc`

`apispec is not valid`

with the following grammar:

```
grammar API;

logEntry    : logLine+;

logLine     : logSubject logCommand logNegate? logRequest EOF;
logSubject  : TEXT+?;
logCommand  : IS;
logNegate   : NOT;
logRequest  : (TEXT|DIGITS)+?;

IS       : 'is';
NOT      : 'not';
TEXT     : [a-zA-Z,]+?;
DIGITS   : [0-9]+;
WS       : [ \r\n\t]+ -> skip;
```

I am having an issue with parsing `apispec is not valid`

The issue that occurs is the literal `is` is part of the `logSubject` which is `apispec`, which antlr4 sees as the `logCommand` instead. How would I configure my grammar to only have `is` be the command if it is surrounded by spaces and have `apispec` show up as the `logSubject`? Or is there a better way to do things?

Comment: Why do you make `TEXT` a non-greedy match? That's what allows a sequence inside a word like `apispec` to be recognized independently.

Comment: *Always* print out the tokens when you are writing a grammar. Your grammar recognizes these tokens: 'a' 'p' 'is' 'p' 'e' 'c' 'is' 'not' 'v' 'a' 'l' 'i' 'd' EOF. The grammar doesn't work because 'is' within 'apispec' is being recognized as a token.

Comment: Antlr lexers are not dependent on the parser. You need to do something like this: `grammar API; logEntry : logLine (NEWLINE logLine)* NEWLINE? EOF; logLine : logSubject logCommand logNegate? logRequest; logSubject : TEXT+; logCommand : IS; logNegate : NOT; logRequest : (TEXT|DIGITS)+; IS : 'is'; NOT : 'not'; TEXT : [a-zA-Z,]+; DIGITS : [0-9]+; NEWLINE : [\r\n]+; WS : [ \r\n\t]+ -> channel(HIDDEN);`.

Comment: Thanks, I should add that I am only sending in 1 line at a time. Newlines are not valid in what I am doing.

Comment: @kaby76 thank you. After removing your NEWLINE addition, You solution worked for me. Looked like I needed to remove my `?` and change skip to `channel(HIDDEN)`. Please submit your answer so I may mark it as the answer and mark this question as solved. Still trying to learn this process myself so thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: Note, you don't really need to change "skip" to "channel(HIDDEN)". They are almost the same, except skip really doesn't generate a token for the white space at all. Yes, it takes a while to get used to Antlr, but it is an excellent tool.